# Error: Expected a value of type 'List<dynamic>', but got one of type '_JsonMap'

Tags: api, mobile, flutter, dart, get

Estou tentando puxar as informações de "animais" com o método get no flutter, mas retorna o seguinte erro:

`Error: Expected a value of type 'List<dynamic>', but got one of type '_JsonMap'`

Meu código:

```
Future<List> getAnimal(int id) async {
    final Client client = InterceptedClient.build(
      interceptors: [
        LoggingInterceptor(),
      ],
    );

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = await prefs.get('token').toString();

    var header = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer ${token}"
    };

    const url = '.../api/animal/';
    final response = await client.get(Uri.parse(url+id.toString()), headers: header);
    var titulo = jsonDecode(response.body);

    final Listanimal;

    final List<dynamic> decodedJson = jsonDecode(response.body) ;
    final Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(response.body);
    final List<AnimalModel> animais = [];

    print("TESTE RETURN ANIMAL");

    return decodedJson.map((json) => AnimalModel.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
```

Acredito que o trecho que está dando problema seja:

````
List<dynamic>? animal;
    animal = RepositoryAnimal().getAnimal(id) as List?;```
````

Answer (score 1):

O erro está na linha do código `final List<dynamic> decodedJson = jsonDecode(response.body) ;`. Você está usando o jsonDecode que retorna um map e está declarando a variável como uma List. O código correto seria assim: `final Map<String, dynamic> decodedJson = jsonDecode(response.body);`. Lembre-se que o retorno é um json em formato de map, e para que você use o seu `return decodedJson.map((json) => AnimalModel.fromJson(json)).toList();`, irá precisar acessar a primeira chave desse json(Map). Seu código final ficaria assim:

```
final Map<String, dynamic> decodedJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
final List<dynamic> jsonList = decodedJson['token'];

return jsonList.map((json) => AnimalModel.fromJson(json)).toList();
```